# Bilinear Functions Not Isomorphic to xy

Tags: bilinear-form

Wolfram Alpha lists $z=xy$ as *an* example of a bilinear function. Are there any others that aren't this form of some product of two objects?

Comment: Also I think isomorphic is the wrong word here

Comment: Should I take it out? I was trying to ask if there was anything that doesn't satisfy same property (is isomorphic) as xy in this way, but maybe I'm comfortable enough with the word isomorphism yet.

Comment: Also, why is z=(0*x)(y) a counterexample?

Comment: Groups can be isomorphic, rings can be isomorphic, graphs can be isomorphic, vector spaces can be isomorphic. But I have never heard of two functions being isomorphic, and I still don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: I think I misused isomorphic, my bad.

Comment: @rbird ok. I BADLY didn’t understand isomorphism. Now that I’m beginning category theory i think I have a better idea of it, but haven’t pondered. Although I have a hand waving notion that maybe if you define a universal property for multiplication, which are unique up to isomorphism...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (column vectors) and an $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Then $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(v,w)=v^tAw$ is a bilinear function.

Given a bilinear function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Fix vector $v$ and then $f(v,\cdot):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear so you can find a matrix $A_v$ so that $f(v,w)=A_vw$ for all $w$ in particular this matrix has to be $1 \times n$ so it's a row-vector. Pick the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$: $e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n$ then 
call $A_i=A_{e_i}$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$ and define $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with rows $A_1, \ldots, A_n$. Note that $$Aw=\begin{bmatrix}A_1w\\ A_2w\\ \vdots \\ A_nw\end{bmatrix}$$

Any $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ has $v=\sum v_i e_i=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{bmatrix}$ so 
$$v^tAw=\sum v_iA_iw=\sum v_i f(e_i,w)=\sum f(v_ie_i,w)=f\left(\sum v_i e_i,w\right)=f(v,w)
$$

So all bilinear forms on a finite dimensional vector space can be defined by a matrix product.

Answer (score 2):

Consider for any matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in M_{m,n}(K)$ a bilinear function defined by
$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_ix_j.
$$

Comment: That is not bilinear. $$f(x,y_1+y_2)=2x+(y_1+y_2)-x(y_1+y_2)$$ $$\neq f(x,y_1)+f(x,y_2)=(2x+y_1-xy_1)+(2x+y_2-xy_2)$$

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you, edited!